# Fragment in FrameLayout in CoordinatorLayout flickers when FrameLayout has LayoutBehavior

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-framelayout

In our app we use a CoordinatorLayout with two Toolbars (top and bottom) that slide out of view when scrolling. Between the Toolbars we have a FrameLayout, thats used to hold a Fragment. Currently we use mainly one Fragment which contains a NestedWebView (https://github.com/takahirom/webview-in-coordinatorlayout). We add the Fragment at runtime by calling fragmentManager.replace().

The Problem is that the FrameLayout seems to often just disappear. Sometimes its gone right from the application start, sometimes it disappears when I click buttons on the top toolbar. When its gone, I can make it show up by rotating the phone or by swiping on the top toolbar. I colored the CoordinatorLayout for debugging purposes and I can clearly see, that sometimes the WebView fills the space as intended, but often the WebView is invisible.

I figured, that the problem does not occur, when I remove

> app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

from the FrameLayout. But of course then scrolling does not work as intended.
Maybe its worth to note, that our Fragment has

> setRetainInstance(true)

set.
Can someone tell me, how I can fix this? Here are the files:

CoordinatorLayout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_behavior=".ui.BottomBarBehavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

WebViewFragment xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.github.dfa.diaspora_android.ui.ContextMenuWebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Some code from our MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main__activity);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbarTop);
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    Menu bottomMenu = toolbarBottom.getMenu();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main__menu_bottom, bottomMenu);
    toolbarBottom.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new ActionMenuView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            return MainActivity.this.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    });

    setupUI(savedInstanceState);
}

private void setupUI(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
    showFragment(StreamFragment.FRAGMENT_NAME);
    ...
    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

private void showFragment(String tag) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    CustomFragment fragment = (CustomFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if (fragment == null) {
        switch (tag) {
            case StreamFragment.FRAGMENT_NAME:
                Log.d(App.TAG, "Create new StreamFragment");
                fragment = new StreamFragment();
                break;
            default:
                Log.e(App.TAG, "Missing fragment "+tag+" in showFragment switch case...");
                return;
        }
    }
    currentFragment = fragment;
    if (!fragment.isVisible()) {
        Log.d(App.TAG, "Fragment not visible. Replace it");
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_container, fragment, tag).commit();
        //Add fragment's bottom menu entries
        currentFragment.onCreateBottomOptionsMenu(toolbarBottom.getMenu(), getMenuInflater());
    } else {
        Log.d(App.TAG, "Fragment was visible");
    }

}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Reinitialize the UI
    setupUI(null);
}
```

Comment: I reported this bug on googles issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222993

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix this issue by changing

> compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'

to

> compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.0'

in my app.gradle file.